# Dynamic Programming with Probabilities on Diedge of DAG

Tags: probability

I have a dynamic programming problem in which I've been asked to calculate the probability of 'surviving a journey' from node $1$ to $6$, along the legs $(1,2)$, $(2,5)$, $(5,6)$. The probability of survival is $0.8$, $0.7$, $0.8$ for each leg respectively.

How do I calculate this probability? Is each leg to be treated as an independent event? Or does this involve conditional probabilities?

Comment: You should clarify your question. How does the graph look like ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply multiplicate the probabilities.

Justification : To survive the whole route, you must survive step $1$ (probability
$0.8$). If you survive step $1$, the (conditional) probability that you also survive step $2$, is $0.7$. Finally, given you survived step $1$ and step $2$, the (conditional) probability to survive is $0.8$.

Comment: Ok, what has thrown me is that it says I should round my answer to 4 dp - but I wouldn't need to in this case. Thanks though :)

Comment: Do you need a simulation or simply a calculation ?